# Controlling a DC Motor via an analog PID circuit

Tags: pid-controller, brushed-dc-motor

I am trying to design a 1 DOF copter as in this drawing:
[image]

For this circuit there is a stick connected to a DC motor and potentiometer.  The potetiometer can be rotated.  I need to control the position of the motor with analaog PID circuit using another potentiometer.

My PID circuit is as below:

[image]

The first potentiometer controls the angle.  The output potentiometer should give feedback.

I am newbie and this circuit does not work, that means my motor does not work when I supply power.

I checked without the motor connected. There is a voltage and everything is okay but after connecting the motor, the voltage is zero and the system does not work.

Because of the pandemic situation, I cannot use the lab equipment to power supply. I think there is not enough current.

- How can I increase the current?
- How can I make sure the PID circuit is working correctly?

Some information my circuit components:

- All op-amps UA741cp
- Other component same with the designed circuit in picture
- My motor is 820 coreless brushed motor set 3.3V =35000-37000 RPM, 5V = 50000 RPM , Size:8 x 20mm, working current min = 0.15A, weight 6.5gr

Comment: There's no way you can drive that motor directly from the opamp output. The 741 can deliver a few milliamperes at most.  The motor needs **much** more current than that.

Comment: Do you suggest an opamp type?

Comment: There's multiple things wrong with that circuit.  Please edit your question with a revised schematic that shows how the op-amps are getting power, and where the motor is in the circuit.  Do you even have power to the op-amps?

Comment: Okay! I updated the schema and it works very well right now in simulation. Now I will set up the reality of the scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the current, I suggest to use  PWM-signal by using output (voltage) signal compare with saw-tooth or triangle signal. Then you can feed PWM signal to Motor drive module or FET to drive motor. This PWM method produce less heat compare linear method.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi0rOS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you really want to drive motor with voltage you can try linear voltage regulator with loss a lot of power to heat as follow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWaG9m.png)</sup>

If you want to make sure that your PID control work currectly , you can test open-loop response with signal generator and osciloscope.

Comment: This comment was very useful for my research, thanks.

Comment: Please add a flyback diode across the motor.

Comment: Thank for remind, using light bulb symbol make me totally forgot to add flyback diode.

Answer (score 1):

[High current from an op amp with or without transistors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/109725/high-current-from-an-op-amp-with-or-without-transistors)

As for testing. Break the problem down into sections and test each section. To test the control loop, that gets a bit tricky, so start with just the P term. Then add the I term. The D term is last. Adjust the coefficients at each stage.

Understand that adjusting a real PID system is not trivial, so expect to make mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment, I will add it here as a reply when I complete the system, but what a voltage source and current value should I have in order to run this circuit, I cannot reach the laboratory due to the pandemic. Now I have a small source that gives current up to 12v and 1 amp, I will get a stronger one, I would be glad if you have suggestions as a component (op-amp type).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This circuit works well for me. I use five LM741 op-amps and one power BJT for motor driving.